# Magento: How to quickly translate product page, category, block, pages?

Tags: magento, translate

We have thousands of products ready in default store view (English). Now, we set up the other 5 store views and each of them stands for a different language.

Magento Languages pack enables to translate interface contents. But cannot translate product page, block, category.

I know we can open each page in Admin and then put "translated content" after choose its store view. It is like we are making 6 stores one by one. This is very time consuming.

Is there any way to bulk or auto translate product page, block, category? For every language, it has unique URL key in its own language? Any extension can do this job?

Thanks